# How to remove moving objects to obtain background only?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm practically new to python and don't have much knowledge about it. I need help converting this pseudocode into Python which is written to obtain the background by removing moving objects in the images. In regards to the Pseudocode, I don't understand the Lines 3, 4 and 5 so maybe once its converted into Python, I can understand it better. In line 3 and 4, I don't understand what the & does and in the last line, I don't understand how is it even computing an image.

Any help will be appreciated.

The code is provided below:

```
Mat sequence[3];// the sequence of images to loop through
Mat output, x = 0, y = 0; // looping through the sequence         
    matchTemplate(sequence[i], sequence[i+1], output, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    mask = 1 & (output>0.9) // get correlated part amongst the images
    x += sequence[i] & mask + sequence[i+1] & mask; // accumulate background infer
    y += 2*mask; // keep count 
end of loop;
Mat bg = x.mul(1.0/y); // average background
```

Sample images to try are also provided below:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P44wT.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU4Yt.jpg)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUbB6.jpg)

Comment: welcome Jack.  more code would be useful and some images.

Comment: Is the question about the algorithm, or implementation? If the latter, you should say whether you understand the pseudocode and if not, why.

Comment: Also, isn't it simpler to just do `for every pixel: take all 3 values from the imgs, drop outlier if any, and bg = avg`?

Comment: I'm practically new to python and don't have much knowledge about it. In regards to the Pseudocode, I don't understand the Lines 3, 4 and 5 so maybe once its converted into Python, I can understand it better. In line 3 and 4, I don't understand what the & does and in the last line, how is it even computing an image.

Comment: you can try doing it @Wassinger. I reckon it's gonna work. Average will show you all the objects in the final image but just a bit faded. Not actually obtain the background without the objects.

Comment: Thank you. This is the complete code that I've posted above. Although, I've attached the pictures for you to try now. The output is the resulting image and x and y are floating point values just so you know. @user1269942

Comment: @JackShane That is why you would first drop outliers before averaging. It would be slightly smudged because of slightly moving grass/shifting light in your photos, but should give a decent result. You can use the same outlier method to build a background mask for each frame also. Your pseudocode also seems to average for bg btw.

Comment: @Wassinger Can you give me an idea on how can I drop the outliers? Because I've been trying to find my way around doing that. Thanks!

Comment: @JackShane There's many methods, but a simple one might be to drop each x where `|x-m| > s*f` where m is mean, s standard deviation, and f is a stringency factor you provide based on what works.

Comment: @Wassinger but you’re using mean to drop outliers. Wasn’t it to be dropped before calculating mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with OpenCV, so I hope you'll excuse me if I don't provide a code snippet you can just copy and paste. But if I understand the pseudocode correctly, it is doing this:

```
sequence = list of images
x will hold sum of backgrounds
y will hold the number of frames use to build x

for each index i in sequence:
    c = matrix of correlation coefficients between (sequence[i], sequence[i+1]) from matchTemplate
    mask = pixels that are highly correlated (90%+)
    x += actual pixels from sequence[i] & mask and sequence[i+1] & mask that are considered background
    y += 2 for every pixel in mask

bg = average of background images x / number of frames y
```

So what's happening is, for every pair of images, it marks the pixels that are the same in both images. The assumption is that background doesn't change between adjacent frames and foreground does. Whether pixels are "the same" is judged on the basis of correlation being >90%. Then it takes all the marked pixels, and averages them.

Comment: Thanks. Here, would I use the ampersand as it is, in Python? Because I still don’t understand how do I implement this code in Python. I already had a bit understanding on what it does.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the commentors mentioned, the mean of the images does remove the foreground but the entire image becomes a little faded. Here is the code that does that:

```
import skimage.io as io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cim1 = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/P44wT.jpg')
cim2 = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU4Yt.jpg')
cim3 = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUbB6.jpg')

x,y,z = cim1.shape
newimage = np.copy(cim1)
for row in range(x-1):
    for col in range(y-1):
        r = np.mean([cim1[row][col][0],cim2[row][col][0],cim3[row][col][0]]).astype(int)
        g = np.mean([cim1[row][col][1],cim2[row][col][1],cim3[row][col][1]]).astype(int)
        b = np.mean([cim1[row][col][2],cim2[row][col][2],cim3[row][col][2]]).astype(int)
        newimage[row][col] = [r,g,b]

fix, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.axis('off')
ax.imshow(newimage)
```

The output image I get from this:

[image]

A better approach to this problem is to find the median of the three images. The more images you have in the algorithm the better is the background. Here is a snippet I tried (just replacing mean with median). If you have more images you can get a much more accurate one.

```
x,y,z = cim1.shape
newimage = np.copy(cim1)
for row in range(x-1):
    for col in range(y-1):
        r = np.median([cim1[row][col][0],cim2[row][col][0],cim3[row][col][0]]).astype(int)
        g = np.median([cim1[row][col][1],cim2[row][col][1],cim3[row][col][1]]).astype(int)
        b = np.median([cim1[row][col][2],cim2[row][col][2],cim3[row][col][2]]).astype(int)
        newimage[row][col] = [r,g,b]


fix, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))   
ax.axis('off')
ax.imshow(newimage)
```

The final output:

[image]

If you had more images, you can completely remove the foreground. Hope you got the idea on which you can build upon.

My code assumes all your images are of the same dimensions. The solution will be a bit more complicated if you captured the images in different views. In that case you may have to use template matching algorithm (your pseudo code seems to be doing something similar) to extract the common canvas from your images.

Comment: Thank you. So, are you saying if a normal person handheld takes some pictures of the same scene (with camera shaking a bit), this won’t apply? @Muthukrishnan

Comment: Were you able to convert the Pseudocode though? Because obviously images are not gonna be as still since they’ll be taken by normal people without any tripod. @Muthukrishnan

Comment: The psuedocode is template matching(line 3) the images whose output is a corr matrix with values between -1 and 1, 1 being a perfect match. the bitwise & operator is giving you a binary of match (the mask) or no match at 0.9 threshold. if match is 1, pixel is copied else not. I ran template match on your images like in the pseudocode, since the images are very different the correlation gives me nothing. Template matching doesn't work if images are of different scale which is your case when pictures are taken without tripod. you may need a scale invariant approach. @JackShane